# istream::getline() not getting the last character?

Tags: c++, file, char, getline

I'm trying to get a full sentence from a file into a character buffer to manipulate further in the program. Using the function getline of istream works perfectly fine until I encounter a sentence ending with "...".

Here is an exemple:

> C'est normal, vous venez de me demander ma main...

I get the input using this code:

```
ifstream Historique;
char buff_char[50];
// other stuff
Historique.getline(buff_char, 50, '\n');
```

What I'm getting:

> C'est normal, vous venez de me demander ma main..

And afterwards, I'm trying to do another `getline` in the files but it fails and I only get an empty character "" in my buffer. I know `getline` is getting `n-1` characters, but I'm telling it where to stop and it works with every other sentence that has only one final punctuation.

Any idea what could be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: The best "fix" would be to use the non-member `std::getline( std::istream &, std::string & )`.

Comment: Have you counted the characters in your sentence? It has 50 characters, but the fixed-buffer variant of `getline` ensures that the buffer is null-terminated. It has nothing to do with the ellispis.

Answer (score 1):

```
getline(buff_char, 50, '\n');
```

Limits the "get" to `50` characters (null-termination included).

> C'est normal, vous venez de me demander ma main...

Is too long.

If wish to use the array buffer, you will need to make it bigger (at least by 1).

The non-member "string" version of [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) is an alternative as well;

```
ifstream Historique;
// ...
std::string line;
std::getline(Historique, line, '\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string

```
C'est normal, vous venez de me demander ma main...
123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|
```

is 50 characters long, but C strings require N+1 characters because they have to store a 'nul terminator' - a byte with a value of 0 that lets C functions know where the string ends.

So you either need to increase your buffer size to 51 bytes or you may want to consider using a C++ [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

```
#include <string>
// ...
ifstream Historique;
std::string buffer;
// other stuff
getline(Historique, buffer, '\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase the size of array `buff_char`

Comment: That doesn't address the problem, since there is no way of preventing a file containing more characters in a line than the buffer can store.

Answer (score 0):

The last character of a char array is always `\0`, so set the array size to one more than what you want.

Comment: Is this a programming question site or English grammar ,people are just correcting my grammer in my questions and answers