# Why does cin.getline() not read the last character when it reads my input and assigns it to a char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, cin, getline

I am new to C++. I don't understand why the `cin.getline()` that I use to assign characters to a character array does not return the "correct" number of characters.

For instance, I have:

```
char st[5];
cin.getline(st,5);
cout<<st;
```

My understanding is that `getline(st, 5)` reads 5 characters from my keyboard and assigns them to `st`. So, suppose I run the above code block and enter `"abcde"`. I would now expect `st` to hold `"abcde"`, but it only holds `"abcd"` instead.  The last character, `e`, gets cut off. Why is this happening?

Comment: Remember that the size should include the string null-terminator. Use `std::string` and `std::getline` instead, to get arbitrarily long strings. Or at least don't be greedy with the array size.

Comment: in those 5 characters you need to be able to fit in [the string's terminating null](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string), so the best you can do is 4 characters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getline skipping one character for char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005963/getline-skipping-one-character-for-char-array) or [istream::getline() not getting the last character?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35498998)

Comment: Useful reference: [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) (There's a list of reasons reading could stop. Point 3: *"`count - 1` characters have been extracted "*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding is that `getline(st, 5)` reads 5 characters from my keyboard and assigns them to `st`.

That is incorrect.  It will read and store up to 4 characters max, and then store a null terminator.  Just as the buffer itself must include room for the terminator, the size you pass in must also account for the terminator.

> The last character, `e`, gets cut off.

It is not "cut off".  It is simply not read to begin with.  It is still sitting in `cin`'s input buffer, waiting for a subsequent read operation to extract it.